# How to style Android Spinner with Material light theme on a dark background?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, material-design

I can't figure out how to style this spinner in a dark-background drawer with the v21 Material theme. I've tried various approaches involving custom styles and nothing seems to make a difference with the appearance of this spinner.

Here's how it looks in the app, running on Android 5.0.1. The spinner, here with the selected item "Code on the Beach 2015", is in a drawer with a dark background (#DD000000), but the rest of the app is a light theme. The arrow shows as black - almost impossible to see on the device. I'd like to make it have a white arrow.

[image: App Screenshot]

Here's my styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="app_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#E95624</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#BD4000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#86d3c5</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And here's the Main.axml file, the main layout for this activity, that contains the DrawerLayout and the Spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:layout_height="match_parent"
    a:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        a:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        a:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        a:elevation="2dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        a:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            a:id="@+id/content_frame"
            a:layout_width="match_parent"
            a:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            a:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            a:orientation="vertical"
            a:layout_width="240dp"
            a:layout_height="match_parent"
            a:layout_gravity="start"
            a:background="#DD000000">
            <Spinner
                a:id="@+id/event_spinner"
                a:layout_width="match_parent"
                a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                a:padding="4dp" />
            <ListView
                a:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
                a:layout_width="match_parent"
                a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                a:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                a:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                a:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in case it is relevant, here is the code that sets the spinner's adapter (Xamarin C#):

```
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(SupportActionBar.ThemedContext, Resource.Layout.event_selector, events);
  adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);

_eventSelector.Adapter = adapter;
```

And here's my event_selector.axml (I changed textColor to #fff after taking screenshot, did not affect arrow color):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

What modifications to my .axml or styles.xml files do I need to make to give this spinner a white arrow? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The key is to set the backgroundTint attribute to the color you want.

```
    <Spinner
      a:id="@+id/event_spinner"
      a:layout_width="match_parent"
      a:layout_height="wrap_content"
      a:padding="4dp" 
      a:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"/>
```